# How does one switch OS users in a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, operating-system

I have a ruby script always initiated by the root user. The script has a certain function called `fou()`. This function needs to be executed as the user 'otherguy' rather than 'root'. How do i switch users mid ruby script, execute the function and then switch back to root?

NEEDS TO BE ONE PROCESS
NO CHILD PROCESSES

OS specific code is welcome as long as it will work for all/most UNIX systems.

EDIT: I'd really prefer a solution without the use of external gems, only what's built into Ruby2.0.0

Comment: How would you expect this to work without a child process? The user, "root" in your case, is already running this file I am unaware of a way to run a portion of this file as another user without forking a process which would end up being a child process. Honestly I am unaware as to how you would do this in any environment regardless of language used. [Example of forking](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2011/01/01/running-a-ruby-block-as-another-user/) in case you change your mind

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah i'm starting to accept the conclusion that this is just impossible. I've been searching for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Process::Sys.seteuid(integer)` and `Process::Sys.setegid` you can change the effective `user id` and `group id`. Don't confound it with `Process::Sys.setuid(integer)` and `Process::Sys.setgid(integer)`. I think

```
Process::Sys.seteuid(12345)
Process::Sys.setegid(54321)
fou()
Process::Sys.seteuid(0)
Process::Sys.setegid(0)
```

is what you are looking for (with Linux).

Comment: Yep that's about it :) found this article after asking this question. Helped a lot: http://timetobleed.com/5-things-you-dont-know-about-user-ids-that-will-destroy-you/